# Trying to get Juniper Firewall Configured

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmi-query, juniper

I will be honest, I am not a firewall guy.

I have been working on a number of Change Controls to get our Juniper Firewall configured to allow the ability to run WMI Queries via PowerShell.

For Example:

```
$time = [System.Management.ManagementDateTImeConverter]::ToDmtfDateTime((Get-Date).AddHours(-24))
$servern = 'SERVER123'
$TomcatEvents=Get-WmiObject Win32_NTLogEvent -ComputerName $servern -Filter "(Message like '%Tomcat%') AND (TimeWritten >= '$time')"
```

I have queried this on both Microsoft's and Juniper's websites and I understand that WMI/DCOM is a range of Ports.  We started with port: 49155 and once that was done, we got hit on port: 49154.

https://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/management/strm/2012_1_R1/strm-common-ports-list.pdf

Our firewall guy would like the range of ports - if possible?

Thanks!

Kent

Comment: 135,1024 through 65535, But if you are trying to traverse firewalls, I recommend making a PSRemoting session then running your command over that.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did some digging on this issue and found:

I did just confirm:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832017

- Start port: 49152
- End port: 65535

Which I believe will cover our needs.

Thanks!

Kent